# php preg_replace text after word+colon

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm getting crazy trying to find the right expression to do that:

Original text:

```
apple:1 10 xxx bla bla bla<br>
orange:2 tic tac toe<br>
lemon:3 123 orange abc<br>
```

To this text:

```
apple:1 10 xxx bla bla bla<br>
orange:<b>2 tic tac toe</b><br>
lemon:3 123 orange abc<br>
```

I tryed something like this but didn't work:

`$text = preg_replace('/orange:(.*)<br>/','<b>$1</b>',$text);`

text after orange: is differnt all the time i run the script so str_replace tic tac toe don't work and without : will also change other string that should keep unchanged.

Comment: Are you actually trying to wrap `2 tic tac toe` in `<b> ... </b>` tags or is that just formatting in the question for emphasis?

Comment: What do you mean not works? What is the problem?

Comment: `$text = preg_replace('/orange:(.*)<br>/','orange: <b>$1</b><br>',$text);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close but there is something you did not consider. The way you wrote the regex there are 2 things that are matched: The word "orange: " and the wildcard (.*). What your regex does is:

- finding the string orange: (SOMETHING)
- replace the first ($1) part of the pattern with itself

So you are finding more or less the right part but you do not really modify it. Here is the code that will work for you:

```
$original = "apple:1 10 xxx bla bla bla
orange:2 tic tac toe
lemon:3 123 orange abc";
$pattern = '/orange:(.*)[^\n]/i';
$replacement = "orange: <b>$1</b>";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $original);
print $text
```

Please note that I assumed that your text is seperated with newline characters `\n` instead of HTML line breaks `<br>`. If that is not the case you need to replace this `[^\n]` with this `[^\<br>]`.

Comment: Happy to help. Would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct.